# only htpps fb app

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, https

How to make only https facebook app?
Couse this code:

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if(empty($data["page"]["liked"]))
```

work in only https.

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only put a HTTPS/secure url in the Application (Canvas or App) Settings.

Leave the Canvas URL blank. And the Secure Canvas URL Populated.

[image]

In addition you can configure your server to Redirect Non HTTP Requests to HTTPS so your Application only servers over HTTPS.

-- Additional

Given your code only works over HTTPS it seems requests to HTTP are being redirected to HTTPS which in my experience tends to drop $_POST'ed data during the redirect as is the case when Facebook loads your App.
Which is why your code trips up because the $_REQUEST is blank/signed_request is missing.